# Compiling using Make

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, torcs

I've got a problem with the command `Make` and `Make Install` in Torcs.

I want to install my own car into the game but when I want to compile I get this problem.

```
reaper@skynet:~/TORCS/torcs-1.3.6/src/drivers/BI0006-BI0038$ sudo make
[sudo] password for reaper:
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

reaper@skynet:~/TORCS/torcs-1.3.6/src/drivers/BI0006-BI0038$ sudo make install
make *** No Rule To Make Target Install'. stop
```

The content of the folder `BI0006-BI0038` where it's supposed to be my car is:

```
reaper@skynet:~/TORCS/torcs-1.3.6/src/drivers/BI0006-BI0038$ ls
bi0006bi0038.cpp  bi0006bi0038.dsp  bi0006bi0038.so   logo.rgb  pw-evoviwrc.rgb
bi0006bi0038.def  bi0006bi0038.o    bi0006bi0038.xml  Makefile
```

I've installed all the packeages and dependencies, and also the game runs perfectly but I need to solve this problem because it is for my university's project.

My TORCS' version is 1.3.6 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(64 bist version).

Answer (score 1):

You can try and follow [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/torcs/mailman/message/30701334/)

> Have a look into the **[robot tutorial](http://www.berniw.org/tutorials/robot/tutorial.html)**, http://www.berniw.org, navigate into the TORCS section.
>   In the "[TORCS installation instructions](http://www.berniw.org/tutorials/robot/torcs/install/torcs-setup.html)", it is explained how to set up the environment.
>
> For "personal work" I usually install `TORCS` in my home directory, then I do not need to mess around with permissions, for that I use "`./configure  --prefix=${HOME}/torcs_bin`".
>
> You can have a look as well into the makefiles of existing robots.